# How i can transfer UIImageView on UIPageViewController transition on swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have 2 ViewControllers on PageViewController, i need transfer UIImageView between them when transition processed (see image).

Maybe someone has an idea how to implement this?
[image: it must be some like that]

Thanks!

Comment: Why not adding two views to UIScrollView side by side and use scrollView's content offset on scroll to move the image

Comment: By the basic logic this should be exactly VC, but i can remove PageVC and us transition - it's not a problem